# Trie iterator hasNext() and null pointer

Tags: java, iterator, trie

I'm trying to implement my iterator and a null pointer keeps showing up. I'm trying to implement the iterator class for a trie of Strings so that I can go through the trie to find potential words and create groups from them. Unfortunately, I just can't get this iterator to work properly.  Can anyone spot this?

```
public class TrieIteratorMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            Unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = { "cat", "mouse", "ball", "dog", "balloon", "fish" };
        Trie wordsTrie = new Trie();

        // copy all words into trie
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println("adding " + word);
            wordsTrie.addWord(word);
        }

        System.out.println();

        Iterator<String> iter = wordsTrie.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) { /* null pointer */
            String word = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Got word: " + word);
            if (word.equals("dog"))
                iter.remove();
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (String word : wordsTrie) {
            System.out.println("Got word: " + word);
        }
    }
}
```

The other class

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class TrieIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private Iterator<String> iter;

    public TrieIterator(Iterator<String> iter) {
        this.iter = iter;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.iter.hasNext();
    }

    public String next() {
        // TODO
        if (! hasNext())   throw new NoSuchElementException();
        String next = this.iter.next();
        return next;
    }

    public void remove() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

update: added TRIE class - though it looks like I didn't save my last edits. I will work on this then update again. So this has most likely been my error the whole time.

Extremely sorry for this. Silly mistake after looking at code for hours on end!

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Trie implements Iterable<String> {
public Trie() {
    // TODO
}

/**
 * This method adds a word to the Trie
 * 
 * @param s
 *            - word to add to the Trie
 */
public void addWord(String s) {
    // TODO
}

/**
 * Returns the root node of the Trie.
 * 
 * @return The root node of the Trie
 */
public TrieNode root() {
    // TODO
    return null;
}

/**
 * This method returns an iterator for the trie, as required by the Iterable
 * interface.
 * 
 * @return and iterator for the trie.
 */
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    // TODO
    return null;
}

/**
 * This method removes all entries from the trie using an iterator.
 */
public void clear() {
    Iterator<String> iter = iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        iter.next();
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Also post the `Trie` class.

Comment: `Iterator<String> iter = wordsTrie.iterator();` is null if you are getting a nullpointer on the next line ( the while loop ). make wordsTrie.iterator() not null

Comment: your edit doesn't mean anything, it's the `Trie` class that matters, you just posted an irrelevant second main method

Comment: The trie class is unfinished at the moment - but I'll post the relevant code

Comment: The `TrieIterator` class just does exactly the same thing as the iterator it's passed.  It provides no change in functionality at all from just using the original iterator in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm trying to get an instance of an iterator from the TrieIterator class to be return.

Comment: My point is that anywhere you return `new TrieIterator(itr)`, you could return `itr` and you'd get the exact same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but here is your null pointer exception reason:

```
/**
 * This method returns an iterator for the trie, as required by the Iterable
 * interface.
 * 
 * @return and iterator for the trie.
 */
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    // TODO
    return null;
}
```

You return null, so it's no question that your attempt to access this method in `trie` returns null and results in a NPE when you attempt to access that null reference

Comment: I'm trying to make an instance of an iterator, possibly. I put the `null` there because the compiler was yelling at me, so I understand where that's coming from.

Comment: I didn't realize that was the issue at the time. Upon having it pointed out, I recalled this.